# List is not being recognized by itertools

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

```
import itertools

#p = input()

def fac(n):
    factorlist = []
    k = 1
    while k < n+1:
        if n % k == 0:
            factorlist.append(k)
            k+=1
            continue
        else:
            k+=1
            continue
    print factorlist
    return factorlist

for a, b in itertools.combinations(factorlist,2):
    if gcd(a,b) == 1:
        print a,b
        continue
    else:
        continue

n=0
while n<=100:
fac(n)
n+=1
```

In the code above, when I try to run itertools.combination the error tells me that factorlist is not defined even though I returned it in the function definition and I am able to print it.

Comment: Is your indentation correct? It looks like you are accessing `factorlist` outside the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable outside of function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905437/using-a-variable-outside-of-function-in-python) keeping in mind that the accepted answer then has `x = run_5()` so you would need to do `factorlist = fac(<someNumber>)` in order to use it globally.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to call the function and get the value into the `factorlist` variable. It exists in the local scope of the function `fac`, but does not exist globally. To fix it, first run `fac` and assign the return value to the variable `factorlist` of the main scope. Then you'll be able to run the for loop without errors:

```
factorlist = fac(some_value)
for a, b in itertools.combinations(factorlist,2):
    do_things
```